# Numbers in your email address

Tags: email

In case the name.lastname@ of an email is already taken, is it ok to add one or two numbers after your last name? 
Are people and employers going to notice such a thing? Is it still professional to use a couple of numbers if no other alternative is possible? Thanks

Comment: Downvoter(s) please remember to explain why you are downvoting.

Comment: @Catsunami probably downvoted due to an easily found duplicate...

Comment: The question should make a good sign post.  No need to vote into oblivion.

Answer (score 3):

> In case the name.lastname@ of an email is already taken, is it ok to add one or two numbers after your last name?

Yes. It is still considered professional.

> Are people and employers going to notice such a thing?

Generally, no. Try to avoid numbers that give away your age and don't use controversial numbers like 666, 69 or 420.

Other strategies, you may want to consider adding a middle initial or a middle name to your email address, or using `_` instead of `.`.

Comment: To add on to this, some professionals I know add location (e.g. "Canada") to their email if they have a common name. So it could be John.smith.canada@gmail.com.

Comment: @Catsunami That might work in Canada, but probably not in the UK...

Comment: Why use _ (underscore) instead of . (dot)? The . seems very customary now.

Comment: @SolarMike, why not? John.smith.london, john.smith.lhr, john.smith.lgw...

Comment: @Brandin I guess it depends on the job. first.last irks people with a programming mind.  I just strung mine in one long word. firstlast@gmail.com.  Then when I send it to people, I send it like FirstLast@gmail.com so it looks good.

Comment: @TrevorD mine is my last name followed by my initials.

Comment: @Brandin Gmail actually disregards the dot in the email address so john.smith@gmail.com and johnsmith@gmail.com will go to the same user, but john_smith@gmail.com is different from johnsmith@gmail.com

Comment: @SolarMike of course it wouldn't work in the UK - why have Canada in your address if you live in the UK? :-)

Answer (score 0):

> In case the name.lastname@ of an email is already taken, is it ok to
>   add one or two numbers after your last name? Are people and employers
>   going to notice such a thing? Is it still professional to use a couple
>   of numbers if no other alternative is possible?

Yes it is professional. If you work for a big company it isn't unusual to have to use numbers to assign unique email addresses. I have seen this on systems that use full names as well as systems that use initials.  Nobody will notice a number and think it is unprofessional.